# Why am I receiving a string from the socket until the \n newline escape sequence in python?

Tags: python, sockets

It is supposed to receive from a tcp socket a 2 line string but in fact i am receiving only the string until the new line.

```
     socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
     socket.connect((ip,port))
     data = socket.recv(1024)
     print "%s" % data
```

if a call the receive function now it will receive the second part of the string after the break line.This is not what i want in fact. It should return the entire string from the first call.
When i use nc to connect to the server i am receiving the string normally in the beginning of the connection.Why that happens?

Comment: generally: don't assume that one recv() call will receive what you send with one send() call, TCP is a stream, not packet/message based.

Comment: I don't want to receive what i send. At the very first connection the server will prompt sth (string\nstring) and i want to catch it with a simple recv

Comment: how do you send the 2 lines message, TCP recv is not supposed to stop when encountering an EOL byte.

Comment: @CédricJulien . I am not the owner of the server

Comment: Do the server send the first line and the prompt as one packet or as two? Is there a "terminator" in the received prompt that says "prompt received, please display"?

Answer (score 11):

Because TCP is a *streaming* protocol (as indicated by the `SOCK_STREAM`) there are no fixed message boundaries or packets, and you can never be sure you get everything with just one call to `recv`. You simply have to call `recv` in a loop, adding to a buffer, and exit the loop when you deem that you have enough. Most text-only protocols use either newline to tell that the read is done and to do something with the received data. Other protocols use other characters, or byte sequences.

In your case, if there is no special character saying that the end of the current data has been reached, you have two solutions:

1. Use a timeout: When no new data has been received for some time, print it.
2. Non-blocking sockets: Simply read in a loop, appending data to an internal buffer. When the call to `recv` throws an error with `errno` equal to `errno.EWOULDBLOCK`, then there is no more to read for now and print the received data.

Alternative 2, together with the package [`select`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html), is probably the best way to go.

### Edit

Here is a simple example of what I mean. It will probably not work like this, and will need some tweaking, but hopefully it's enough for you to build on.

```
# Need to import: package socket, package select, package errno

# Create socket and connect to server

# Make the socket non-blocking (see http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking)
socket.setblocking(0)

run_main_loop = True
while run_main_loop:
    # Wait for events...
    read_ready, _, _ = select.select([socket], None, None)

    if socket in read_ready:
        # The socket have data ready to be received
        buffer = ''
        continue_recv = True

        while continue_recv:
            try:
                # Try to receive som data
                buffer += socket.recv(1024)
            except socket.error, e:
                if e.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                    # Error! Print it and tell main loop to stop
                    print 'Error: %r' % e
                    run_main_loop = False
                # If e.errno is errno.EWOULDBLOCK, then no more data
                continue_recv = False

    # We now have all data we can in "buffer"
    print '%r' % buffer

socket.close()
```

Comment: Does the Python library seriously not provide an applicable wrapper for this at a higher level? (I guess it depends on what OP is really trying to do, overall...)

Comment: @Joachim . Can you give me simple practical example. I totally confused. I was not thinking that it would be so tricky

Comment: @KarlKnechtel not last time I checked. I'm so missing the C++ boost asio's streams + `read_until()`. Especially if I don't want to read past the sequence, which may block for longer than I want...

Comment: I don't see why you would switch to nonblocking just to select on a single open socket. Looks like a red herring. He  should just recv blocks until one of them has the delimiter, return the part until first delimiter and keep the extra part for the next line. If recv result is empty, that means server finished sending.